# Timeout Error when server.py and client.py connect on two separate "Windows" ec2 instances?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, python-sockets

I have a basic server and client that I need to be able to communicate. They work locally with no problem but as soon as I upload them onto their ec2 instances I get the timeout error on the client side.

(each instance is on its own aws account...the server is on one account and the client is on another)

"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

I believe it's an issue with ports and/or permissions, but I am unsure how to resolve it as everything I read is about remote connection...which is fine.

For the time being I have allowed all tcp connections from any ip for testing but will change the security group when it is working.

server.py

```
import socket

HEADER_LEN = 10
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 9999


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()

while True:

    connection, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")

    msg = "Welcome to the server!"
    msg = f"{len(msg):<{HEADER_LEN}}" + msg

    connection.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))

    while True:


        msg = input()
        msg = f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}" + msg

        connection.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
```

client.py

```
import socket

HEADER_LEN = 10
HOST = "6.134.121.189"
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    full_message = ''
    new_message = True
    while True:
        message = s.recv(16)
        if new_message:
             message_len = int(message[:HEADER_LEN])
             new_message = False

        full_message += message.decode("utf-8")

        if (len(full_message) - HEADER_LEN > 0) and (len(full_message)- 
                                                HEADER_LEN == message_len):
    
            print(full_message[HEADER_LEN:])
            
            new_message = True
            full_message = ''
```

Comment: can you add more information, is this a public subnet or private subnet?  The IP you have listened looks like a public IP but if the subnet is a private subnet, this may explain the issue... have you tried using the private IP address for connecting?

Comment: Sorry its a public IP...Each instance lives on different aws accounts....they are not in the same subnet. I should of specified.

Comment: But can you confirm that the instances are on public subnets?  what are the route tables associated with the subnets that the instances are in?   

That being said, I would recommend doing the communication between these instances privately.  This can be accomplished by peering the VPCs in your two accounts.

Comment: Okay things I have done.

Comment: Okay things I have done.

1). Created new vpc, subnet, route tables and internet gateway link all together.
2). Created new security group that allows rdp and all connections through tcp(temporary)
3). Created new server instance using new vpc and subnet, also allowing public ip

Still unable to connect. 

Not 100% what im doing wrong here...For now I am just testing the server and I have the client on my local machine.

Comment: I can now confirm that its a public subnet and the route table has 0.0.0.0/0 associated to it

Comment: if your server is on a windows box, can you double check that the windows firewall is turned off?  perhaps enable icmp in the SG and verify if you can ping the box

Comment: not responding to ping. I enabled icmp in SG and restart instance.

Comment: going to disable firewall and test

Comment: need to add an exception on the windows server...ummm im stupid lol thank you so much please put as an answer so I can accept..also going to look into peering..thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of issues are typically some sort of network routing issue.

Enable ICMP in your SG and see if you can ping your machine, if you can't then this is definitely a network routing issue and you can check some of the following:

1. Verify the machine is on a public subnet.  AWS allows you to give an instance a public IP even though it's on a private subnet.  This is confusing and and being on a private subnet will prevent anything from routing to it from the internet (even if it has a public/elastic IP).
2. Verify that the Windows firewall is disabled on your instance.  It's best practice to just disable the OS-level firewall so you can control the rules via SGs and NACLs in AWS.